# Can I define a property which is available to both the class type and instances of the class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an interface for a base class, and every class that inherits from the base class should have an identifying field which tells the application what kind of object it is.

I wanted to use this property in two different ways:

Without creating an instance of the object

```
if (someValue == TestA.Id)
    return new TestA();

elseif (someValue == TestB.Id)
    return new TestB();
```

And as a property of the interface

```
void DoSomething(ITest testObject)
{
    SomeValue = testObject.Id;
}
```

Is there an easy way to define the `Id` field in the interface, but still have it available to use without creating an instance of the class?

Right now I am using the following code. I could add a read-only `Id` property to the interface which returns the const string, however I was hoping there was a simpler way that I'm just not aware of.

```
public interface ITest
{

}

public class TestA : ITest
{
    public const string Id = "A";
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422246/providing-inherited-static-properties-conceptually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short - no.

In order to be able to do this, you'd need to be able to specify this as a instance property on the interface (and implement it in the instance), and as a static property on the type.

The compiler won't let you do this.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I wasn't able to figure it out on my own, but thought I'd ask here before giving up completely because there is a lot about C# I still don't know

Comment: I can see how it would be useful, but alas no.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the interface, and also have it as a static property.  Something like:

```
interface IInterface { Id { get; } }

class Class : IInterface
{
  public static Id { get { return 1; } }
  public Id { get { return Class.Id; } }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I plan on doing if there's no easier way. There's a lot about C# I don't know still, so I was hoping there was a way around creating two properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem, Rachel, and I've always (unfortunately) resorted to having that factory code rely on reflection to get a "TypeID" public static property on each concrete type... thus making an additional aspect of the contractual interface, but not having it in the C# interface code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way.

```
public interface ITest
{
    SomeValue Id{ get;}
}


public class TestA : ITest
{
    public SomeValue Id 
    {
       get {return TestA.StaicId; }
    }

    public static SomeValue StaticId
    {
         get {return "This is TestA";}
    }
}


if (someValue == TestA.StaticId)
       return new TestA();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using attributes? Here's a small example of what can be done:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IdAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IdAttribute(string id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IMyInterface
{
    public static string GetId<T>() where T : IMyInterface
    {
        return ((IdAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IdAttribute), true)[0]).Id;
    }
}

[Id("A")]
public class ImplA : BaseClass
{
}

[Id("B")]
public class ImplB : BaseClass
{
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var val1 = BaseClass.GetId<ImplA>();

        var val2 = BaseClass.GetId<ImplB>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but was hoping there was a simpler way. Since there isn't, I plan on just exposing a 2nd copy of the property on my such as what Kyle suggested.